# Cloned element can't be removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a grid where if a user hovers over a box, a clone of that box is made and positioned directly over it (it's a z-index/overlay thing). When the user leaves that box with the cursor, an animation is supposed to play and at the end of it the box is removed().

The problem is that the animation completes but the clone isn't removed. I use console.logs and alerts to tell me if the animation completes and it alerts fine but anything to be done to that cloned client after animation completes doesn't go through. Here's an example:

```
clonedClient.slideUp(300, function(){
        alert('ya');
        clonedClient.remove();
});
```

After the slideUp completes, alert is triggered but remove isn't.

Here's a jsfiddle so you can see what's happening

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6fVP/1/

Comment: The `remove` is being called.  It's just that you have multiple clones in the DOM.  It's removing one of the clones, but the others are still there, and keep being added on `mouseenter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mouseenter event is triggered twice (because the `selected-client` clone, also has a class of `client`. If you add console.log in the mouseenter event, you'll notice:

```
entering <div class=​"client">​hello​</div>​
entering <div class=​"client selected-client" style=​"background-color:​ red;​ position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 0.5em;​ background-position:​ initial initial;​ background-repeat:​ initial initial;​">​hello​</div>​
```

You'll want to omit the mouseenter event if the element that it is being triggered on is your `selected-client`.

i.e. in your first event handler:

`if($this.hasClass('selected-client')){return;}`

or, more completely, for that block of code:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.hasClass('selected-client')){
            return;
        }
        var clientClone = $this.clone().css({background:'red', position:'absolute', top: '0.5em'}).addClass('selected-client');
        clientClone.insertBefore(this);
    }
}, 'div.client');
```

Comment: Could you not instead add a `:not('selected-client')` to the original selector?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$(document).on()`, which means the event handler is attached to document. When you cloned your `<div>` element, the class `.client` was also applied to the clone. And when you inserted the clone after the original, `mouseenter` was fired again, because you entered the newly cloned element (another clone was made here).

My solution is to remove `.client` class from the clone before inserting.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6fVP/8/

Comment: I would remove .client but it's also tied to css styles

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I think you want to replace `clonedClient.remove();`

with `$('.selected-client').remove();`